# Searching model using 'like ?' returning error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`MyModel.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{'black'}%")` gives the error: **wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)**

`MyModel.where(["name ILIKE ?", "%#{'black'}%"])` gives the error: **expected a clauses Hash, got ["title ILIKE ?", "%black%"]**

It seems like I've tried a dozen variations. With and without %'s, like ? vs like?, like vs ILIKE, etc. I always seem to get the same errors.

Comment: What version of Rails are you on? And it looks like you might be using Sequel, not ActiveRecord.

Comment: @RobertNubel Rails v4.2.3. And does Sequel not allow LIKE queries?

Comment: I believe it does, but not with the same `where` syntax as Rails. Try `MyModel.filter(Sequel.ilike(:name, '%black%'))`.

Comment: Can you please state explicitly if you use Sequel (or activerecord, or something different)? please edit your question.